# How to test if an array has specific data in a specific order

Tags: java, arrays

I need to test if an array

```
int arr2[4];
```

has specific data in a specific order. In my case I need to test if `arr2[4];` has the following data: 2,3,3,5. I tried this but to no avail:

```
 if (arr2 = {2,3,3,5}){
    //whatever
 }
```

Otherwise I suppose I can just create an array "arr3" with data 2,3,3,5 and then test if arr2 = arr3... I don't know. Maybe I can't even do that!

Will be very glad if someone can help me in this matter!

Comment: Really, instead of randomly trying things, get yourself a book or good tutorial and start reading.

Comment: I do have a book and I read a lot of things before asking this question. I couldn't find anything useful and decided someone here will not mind helping.

Comment: That is indeed the correct approach. Continue asking questions for anything you don't completely understand. Good luck with your learning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Array.equals`.

```
if (Arrays.equals(myArray, new int[] {2,3,3,5}) {
    // do this!
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it and accept your answer in 10min ;)

Comment: Does that syntax actually work in this context?  I would've thought it'd have to be `.equals(myArray, new int[] (2,3,3,5})`. If it does, then thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the `Arrays.asList` route doesn't work for primitive arrays.  It wii create a `List<int[]>` with one element, not a `List<Integer>`.  But still upvoted for teh right solution with `Arrays.equals()`.

Comment: Should a temporary variable should be created first? It's been a while since I used Java. I'll update.

Comment: @Closure: that's a possibility.  It's unfortunate that there's no core Java library that lets you switch between arrays of primitives and collections of their wrapper class.

Comment: @Closure: I didn't realizes that's what you meant by intermediary.  No, unfortunately your correction is subject to the same behaviour.  `containsAll` doesn't respect order anyways so I'm not sure that part of your answer is providing much to the question anyhow.

Comment: @markpeters That's embarrassing. >.< Thanks again, and I'm sorry for being dense!